# PHP Submit form & Image stored image filename in database

Tags: php, forms, upload

Ok So. This has been driving me crazy.
I want a form to 'add a product' which places data X Y Z into database which works fine and post to self without issues.(As I removed the image part).

I now want to upload a file, I presume use

```
<form action="thissameurl.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="productimage">
</form>
```

To add to my form (just the input bit would be added).

Now, what do I need to add to my 'if post' section in the header to allow me to..

1.) Upload the file to a permanent folder

2.) Keep the original file name

3.) Have the filename (not the path) in a variable so that I can store it in the database.

Now im a sure this isn't as difficult as it seems to be. I am open to other technologies if they make it easier than using PHP. The files aren't going to be very large and have check that PHP.ini allows for them to be good enough.

I have looked at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp without much success.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't stop/limit yourself to W3 Schools, which in many a people's opinion is not the best resource. Keep Googling, you WILL find answers that may very well lead you to Q&A's here on SO. Keywords **"php upload database mysqli pdo"** that are sure to get you results.

Comment: Have you at least read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: I have checked the php.net example 3 just gives an error. Invalid argument supplied for 'in each'

Comment: @MattHorner A `foreach` is for multiple uploads at once or for an array of allowed files, depending on what "your" `foreach` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need

1.) Upload the file to a permanent folder --> use move_uploaded_file().
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

2.) Keep the original file name  --> $_FILES["file"]["name"] has the original name

3.) Have the filename (not the path) in a variable so that I can store it in the database. --> Store value of $_FILES["file"]["name"].